# typeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I tried very hard to find a solution to this problem, but I didn't find anything, could anyone help?

I just want to fetch this data.

typeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined -> Error

```
import styles from '../styles/galery.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import photo from '../public/01.png'

export const getStaticProps = async () => {

    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/rocketseat');
    const data = await response.json();

    return {
        props: { mods: data }
    }
}

const ProjectLines = ({ mods }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.categoryWrapper}>
            <h4 className={styles.subTitle}>Escritório</h4>
            <div className={styles.lineWrapper}>
                <a className={styles.leftArrow}>&#10094;</a>
                <div className={styles.line}>
                    {mods.map(mod => (
                        <div className={styles.imageBox}>
                            <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
                            <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                                <span className={styles.name}>{mod.login}</span>
                                <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <a className={styles.rightArrow}>&#10095;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ProjectLines;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to use getStaticProps in a component archive, it need to be used in a page... Thanks everyone.

[NextJS Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page)

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

Yow all this comments all they do is confusing. The solution is very simple right before you map them mods check if they exists how ?

```
{mods && mods.map(.....
```

That's one way or the other is to add a default value

```
({ mods = []}) =>
```

But do the first one, is better

Comment: It did work, but the card unfortunately disappeared

Comment: Card ? Which card ? It did not disappeared because it never was rendered. You is never using getStaticProps or how a s it connected to yow component

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the data and passing it properly, but unfortunately, it is not an array, it's an object. The `.map` function is used on arrays to go through every element, almost like an `forEach` but here they are returned.

What you'll need to do is create a component for `Organizations` which will have the props from the object fetched, then the array of organizations will need to be traversed, if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

well, the error is simple basically the response that you are getting is a `json` object, a plain json object.

with this said, basically you can not map over a object or well, you can but not using map.

the response of the url is

```
{
    login: "Rocketseat",
    id: 28929274,
    node_id: "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjI4OTI5Mjc0",
    url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat",
    repos_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/repos",
    events_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/events",
    hooks_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/hooks",
    issues_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/issues",
    members_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/members{/member}",
    public_members_url: "https://api.github.com/orgs/Rocketseat/public_members{/member}",
    avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/28929274?v=4",
    description: "Plataforma de educação em tecnologia ",
    name: "Rocketseat",
    company: null,
    blog: "https://rocketseat.com.br",
    location: null,
    email: "opensource@rocketseat.com.br",
    twitter_username: "rocketseat",
    is_verified: true,
    has_organization_projects: true,
    has_repository_projects: true,
    public_repos: 23,
    public_gists: 0,
    followers: 0,
    following: 0,
    html_url: "https://github.com/Rocketseat",
    created_at: "2017-05-24T16:16:47Z",
    updated_at: "2021-10-04T18:42:26Z",
    type: "Organization"
}
```

so if you want to display only the login as I think you want you need to do this:

```
const ProjectLines = ({ mods }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.categoryWrapper}>
            <h4 className={styles.subTitle}>Escritório</h4>
            <div className={styles.lineWrapper}>
                <a className={styles.leftArrow}>&#10094;</a>
                <div className={styles.line}>
                    <div className={styles.imageBox}>
                        <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
                        <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                            <span className={styles.name}>{mod.login}</span>
                            <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a className={styles.rightArrow}>&#10095;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but if you want to loop over each key you should do this:

```
{Object.values(mods || {}).map(mod => (
    <div className={styles.imageBox}>
        <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
            <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                <span className={styles.name}>{mod}</span>
                <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
            </div>
    </div>
))}
```

hope it helps and you understand the issue with your code.

Comment: the first option you gave to me say: "typeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: The second option you gave to me say: "typeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: @GustavoLeterio the problem is that you copy pasted everything without think or at least reading the solution and what was your problem.
I edited the solution, try again and if something fails at least try to debug or look for the error, it is not so hard that you are using wrong the functions of different structures.

Answer (score 0):

the url you are using here

> (https://api.github.com/orgs/rocketseat)

to fetch data giving object in return and map functions are for array.

if you want to use the value remove the map and use the object itself.

```
<div className={styles.line}>
                        <div className={styles.imageBox}>
                            <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
                            <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                                <span className={styles.name}>{mods.login}</span>
                                <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

just change this part and you are good to go.

Comment: This alteration doesn't work, beacause login don't exist "typeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add verification for each value of `const ProjectLines`

You have now:

```
<div className={styles.line}>
                    {mods.map(mod => (
                        <div className={styles.imageBox}>
                            <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
                            <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                                <span className={styles.name}>{mod.login}</span>
                                <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

You need to implement (for each variable you are using in return):

```
{mods ? 
<div className={styles.line}>
                    {mods.map(mod => (
                        <div className={styles.imageBox}>
                            <Image src={photo} width={400} height={200} layout="responsive" lazy="true" placeholder="blur" />
                            <div className={styles.linkContent}>
                                <span className={styles.name}>{mod.login}</span>
                                <Link href=""><a className={styles.link}>Veja Mais!</a></Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
</div>
: ''}
```

Why so? because of usage [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation). It's async function, check properly docs.

Also for the `.map` function. Somebody tells that .map can be implemented with objects, that is `true`. !BUT! you have to `console.log(typeof(mods))`, and I am 90% sure you have it as `array` object. In any case, you have undefined value in mods, it means it's `null`, and not triggering "isObject" error.

Comment: It did work, but the card unfortunately disappeared